# could not open terminal for stdout

Tags: java, linux, gradle

Estou tendo um problema com gradle ao executar qualquer comando me é retornado a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
* What went wrong:
     Could not open terminal for stdout: could not get termcap entry
```

Vizualização do erro no pastebin  https://pastebin.com/NJTgDy7M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, isso é um problema com uma lib chamada `ncurses5-compat-libs`, que interfere com o funcionamento normal do Gradle. Tente desinstalá-la e execute novamente algum comando do Gradle.

Se não funcionar, configure a variável de sistema `TERM` para `xterm-color`:

`export TERM=xterm-color`

Fonte: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4426